# NASM X86 read_int 08 vs 8

Tags: assembly, input, x86, nasm

*I edited the post so jump down to **EDIT1** to see the current version.*

I made a program which prints out a specific fibonacci number in binary(if my input is 5, it prints the 5th fibonacci number, which is 5, so the output is 0000 0000 0000 0101b). The problem I'm facing is that if my input is 8, output is 13(10101b), but if my input is 08 my output is 1111001000111011b.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
    zero_msg db "0000000000000000",0
    one_msg db  "0000000000000001",0
    invalid_msg db "Invalid input 0000_0000",0

segment .text
    global  _asm_main

_asm_main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha

    call read_int
    mov edx,eax
    cmp eax, 0
    je zero
    cmp eax, 1
    je one
    cmp eax, 100
    jge invalid_input
    call fibonacci

    popa
    leave
    ret

invalid_input:
    mov eax,invalid_msg
    call print_string
    jmp end
zero:
    mov eax, zero_msg
    call print_string
    jmp end
one:
    mov eax,one_msg
    call print_string
    jmp end

print_binary:
    shl ecx, 1
    jc print1
    mov eax,0
    call print_int
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx,16
    jne print_binary
    jmp end

print1:
    mov eax,1
    call print_int
    je end
    jmp print_binary


%define fib_hi  dword [ebp-4]
%define fib_lo  dword [ebp-8]
fibonacci:
    enter   16,0            
    push    ebx

    mov   ecx, 1            
    mov   fib_lo,1        
    mov   fib_hi,1       
fib_loop:
    mov   eax,fib_hi    
    mov   ebx,fib_lo
    add   ebx,eax
    mov   fib_lo,eax
    mov   fib_hi,ebx
    inc   ecx
    cmp   ecx,edx
    jne   fib_loop
    mov   ecx,eax
    mov   ebx,0
    shl   ecx,16 
    jmp   print_binary
    end:
      mov   eax,'b'
      call  print_char    
      pop   ebx
      leave                  
      ret
```

read_int is from asm_io.asm file which I was given. This is what it looks like.

```
read_int:
    enter   4,0
    pusha
    pushf

    lea eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    dword int_format
    call    _scanf
    pop ecx
    pop ecx

    popf
    popa
    mov eax, [ebp-4]
    leave
    ret
```

**EDIT1:** So I made it a little cleaner and it's working well except for 08 and 09. I realised that if my inputs are 08 or 09, the cpu/nasm/...(don't know which) thinks that my input is 0. I tested it with a print_string command.
Here's the code right now:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
    invalid_msg db "Invalid input 0000_0000",0

segment .text
    global  _asm_main
_asm_main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha

    call read_int
    mov edx,eax
    cmp eax,0
    js invalid_input        
    je zero
    cmp eax,1
    je one
    cmp eax,100
    jge invalid_input
    call fibonacci

    popa
    leave
    ret
invalid_input:
    mov eax,invalid_msg
    call print_string
    jmp end
zero:
    mov eax,0
    jmp shift
one:
    mov eax,1
    jmp shift   
print_binary:
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx,17
    je end
    shl ecx,1
    jnc print_0
    mov eax,1
    call print_int
    cmp ebx,17
    jne print_binary
    jmp end
print_0:
    mov eax,0
    call print_int
    jmp print_binary

%define fib_hi  dword [ebp-4]
%define fib_lo  dword [ebp-8]

fibonacci:
    enter   8,0            
    push    ebx

    mov   ecx,0         
    mov   fib_lo,0        
    mov   fib_hi,1       
fib_loop:
    mov   eax,fib_hi    
    mov   ebx,fib_lo
    add   ebx,eax
    mov   fib_lo,eax
    mov   fib_hi,ebx
    inc   ecx
    cmp   ecx,edx
    jne   fib_loop
shift:
    mov   ecx,eax
    mov   ebx,0
    shl   ecx,16
    jmp   print_binary
end:
    mov eax,'b'
    call print_char   

    pop ebx
    leave                  
    ret
```

Comment: The 8th Fibonacci is 21 (10101). The `fibonacci` function is a bit weird but it works for the valid input range. The `print_binary` function has the `print1` branch wrong. You can replace the branching with an `adc` or make the branch just set `eax` and reenter at `call print_int`. I assume flags are preserved by the IO functions. I don't see how you could get the output you posted though.

Comment: Yeah, I had something at my print1 branch, and didnt delete je end. Made the change and now its doing well for almost every input but two.  08 and 09. These two are making the mess here. @MargaretBloom